# Google pageSpeed FATAL:css_summarizer_base.cc

Tags: pagespeed

Time to time we have this error in pagespeed logs, as a result nginx return 503 error.

We include all acceptable modules exept module of sprites

```
2015/09/11 15:51:50 [alert] 27945#27948: [ngx_pagespeed 1.9.32.3-4448] [0911/155150:FATAL:css_summarizer_base.cc(327)] Check failed: canceled_summaries_.empty().
nginx: worker process() [0x5bdf41]
nginx: worker process() [0x5baf5a]
nginx: worker process() [0x6ba535]
nginx: worker process() [0xa34402]
nginx: worker process() [0x7b7bd2]
nginx: worker process() [0x7b47cd]
nginx: worker process() [0x603ba4]
nginx: worker process() [0x604087]
nginx: worker process() [0x5ad05d]
nginx: worker process() [0x5ad6f8]
nginx: worker process() [0x5b426a]
nginx: worker process() [0x7564be]
nginx: worker process() [0x8202db]
nginx: worker process() [0x822bd3]
nginx: worker process() [0x7564be]
nginx: worker process() [0x82ba3b]
nginx: worker process() [0x82e1d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50) [0x7fd56825db50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fd564eb895d]

nginx: worker process() [0x5bdf41]
nginx: worker process() [0x54820d]
nginx: worker process() [0x5bb03c]
nginx: worker process() [0x6ba535]
nginx: worker process() [0xa34402]
nginx: worker process() [0x7b7bd2]
nginx: worker process() [0x7b47cd]
nginx: worker process() [0x603ba4]
nginx: worker process() [0x604087]
nginx: worker process() [0x5ad05d]
nginx: worker process() [0x5ad6f8]
nginx: worker process() [0x5b426a]
nginx: worker process() [0x7564be]
nginx: worker process() [0x8202db]
nginx: worker process() [0x822bd3]
nginx: worker process() [0x7564be]
nginx: worker process() [0x82ba3b]
nginx: worker process() [0x82e1d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b50) [0x7fd56825db50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fd564eb895d]
2015/09/11 15:51:50 [alert] 8226#8226: worker process 27945 exited on signal 6
```

This is a main config nginx, maybe it is help

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  12;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  10240;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;  

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format detailed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $host '
                        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                        '$pid $connection $request_time $msec '
                        '$upstream_status $upstream_response_time';

  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;




  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/json;

  #set_real_ip_from 81.91.183.0/24;
set_real_ip_from 81.91.182.0/23;
  #real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
  #real_ip_recursive on;

  proxy_set_header    Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  proxy_hide_header       X-Powered-By;
  server_tokens           off;

  proxy_connect_timeout   75;
  proxy_send_timeout      90;
  proxy_read_timeout      90;

  fastcgi_connect_timeout   75;
  fastcgi_send_timeout      90;
  fastcgi_read_timeout      90;

  proxy_buffer_size 128k;
  proxy_buffers 4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size  256k;
  client_body_buffer_size     128k;
  client_max_body_size        1m;

    pagespeed off;
        pagespeed FileCachePath /mnt/pagespeed;
    pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb            4096000;
    pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs   900000;
    pagespeed RewriteLevel PassThrough;
     pagespeed CssFlattenMaxBytes 5120;
     pagespeed EnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries;
     pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
     pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css;
     pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;
     pagespeed EnableFilters elide_attributes;
     pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
     pagespeed EnableFilters fallback_rewrite_css_urls;
     pagespeed EnableFilters flatten_css_imports;
     pagespeed EnableFilters inline_images;
     pagespeed EnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch;
     pagespeed EnableFilters lazyload_images;
     pagespeed EnableFilters outline_css;
     pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
     pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_jpeg;
     pagespeed EnableFilters recompress_png;
     pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments;
     pagespeed EnableFilters resize_images;
     pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css;
     pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_domains;
     pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_images;
     pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_javascript;
pagespeed MapOriginDomain "santehnika-online.ru" "www.santon.cdnvideo.ru";
#pagespeed MapRewriteDomain "santehnika-online.ru" "www.santon.cdnvideo.ru";
pagespeed MapRewriteDomain "www.santon.cdnvideo.ru" "santehnika-online.ru";





  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # Common settings for nginx-push-stream-module
  push_stream_shared_memory_size 1024M;
  push_stream_max_messages_stored_per_channel 4000;
  push_stream_max_channel_id_length 32;
  push_stream_max_number_of_channels 400000;
  push_stream_message_ttl 86400;
  push_stream_channels_path $arg_CHANNEL_ID;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I have no idea. What is wrong with server?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

The check failure you mention only occurs in debug builds of ngx_pagespeed. To work around you could run a release build.

The issue is tracked at https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/891
The offending line is h